# How Can I Convert the Mat to Int? (c++, Gpu, OpenCV)

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, gpu

I'm trying to convert the math to int but it doesn't work. I have searched on the internet about the converting but didn't find anything for me.

1. How can we convert an `array` to `mat`?
2. How can we convert `mat` to an `array`?
3. What kind of way should I use?

Comment: C++ has no "mat". A matrix can be stored in an array by just deciding an order (colums first or rows first) and then puting each element one by one. Other way is using multidimensional arrays (e.g. myarray[3][4])

Comment: @Ripi2 Notice that OpenCV is mentioned at least twice. That's where [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) comes from.

Comment: How is this related to `gpu` tag?

Comment: I guess that he has to swap between both because he does GPU operations that he has defined himself but he also uses OpenCV functions. With that, as far as I know, you can only work with arrays rather than complex types like `cv::Mat`

Comment: 'double sxthresh[2]={20, 255};
Mat sx_thresh(1,2,CV_32F,sxthresh);
Mat scaled_sobel=255*absob/maxabsob;
Mat sxbinary=Mat::zeros(1,2,CV_32F);
sxbinary[scaled_sobel > sx_thresh[0]] = 1; '

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `mat` class is indeed `cv::Mat` (since you specify that you use OpenCV in the topic), you can have a look to all of the `cv::Mat` functions and constructors [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjn567iuOvVAhWc14MKHaCLAR0QFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.opencv.org%2F3.1.0%2Fd3%2Fd63%2Fclasscv_1_1Mat.html&usg=AFQjCNFeAFOcCjBJ4hDaGVNSo1rjIv40dA). There you can see there is a [constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) to which you can pass a pointer to the data. An example is:

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(2,6,CV_32SC1,array1);
```

To retrieve the data in the mat as an array (following from previous code)

```
int* array2;
if (mat.sContinuous())
    array2 = mat.ptr<int>(0);
```

If the matrix is not continuous then you will most likely have to copy it element by element.